# General Private/Public key generation

Tags: public-key, cryptocurrency, key-generation

I wanted to get an idea on how the whole cold-storage private/public key generation works for different cryptocurrencies. So I was playing around with BIP32 deriviation path on:
https://iancoleman.io/bip39/#english

I noticed that for example BTC, XRP, PIRL all have the same BIP32 root key and BIP32 extended private/public key, but DOGE was completely different.
Why is that? BTC hashing algorithm is SHA256 and PIRL uses Scrypt, their root seeds are the same, while DOGE which uses Dagger has a different seed and private/public key.

The second part that I don't understand is the generation process of addresses for different cryptocurrencies, is there a web site where I could look up on how it's done? The only one I found is for bitcoin here https://www.mobilefish.com/services/cryptocurrency/cryptocurrency.html#refMethod2

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is already answered [at bitcoin.SE](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/78753/29414)